COGs as WMS data source for GeoServer
We have a problem setting up the GeoServer for a specific scenario: in total we have more than 12.000 images (in COG format, located in s3 bucket) that shall be published as WMS service. The images cover different spatial and temporal extents - the resulting WMS should have the full extent. Unfortunately it seems that GeoServer is not capable of handling a bucket with many files. We checked the COG module, but it is only possible to have one single file as input data.
Please note that we are using the GeoServer Cloud version as we are running in a cloud environment.
Are there any ideas how to set up the WMS? Would an Image Mosaic be the right way to do this? Do you have any suggestion regarding our approach?

It sounds like you want a mosaic rather than a single file - see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/cog/update.html

Dear Vince, thanks for your answer. Yes, we also tried to create a mosaic image following this tutorial. We performed the steps in the tutorial, but we encounter a problem ("java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader..."). It seems like it's not working anymore - we also found someone with the same problem: link. Is this a known issue?

Is there an issue in Jira? If there's not then no it's not a known issue and you should add it. You'll need to fix it too

Dear Ian (Sorry for calling you Vince before), thanks for your answer. I think we found a related issue there - unfortunately it's not closed yet.

So there's an opportunity for you to make a contribution to the program

Yes, why not. I fear my GeoServer knowledge is not sufficient to do it now - but I'll try to dive into the GeoServer topic.

There are commercial suppliers you can hire too
